# Default value of BOOL

Tags: objective-c, initialization, boolean

What is the default value of a `BOOL` variable in Objective-C?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

There is *no* default value if you write

```
-(void)somemethod {
  BOOL x;  // <--- no default value
```

It is initialized to garbage.

However, for a `BOOL` *ivar*, it will be initialized to `NO`, as the whole instance is filled with 0 on initialization.

(Note: When ARC is enabled, local *object pointers* will always be have a default value `nil`, but local variables of non-object types like BOOL are still initialized to garbage. See [Local variables set to nil? (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022025/local-variables-set-to-nil-objective-c).)

Comment: Can you count on the non ivar BOOL to always be the same garbage?  or is it different? (ie. I'm seeing it evaluate to the integer value of '2' in a NSlog statement)

Comment: @bentford The ivar is initialized to `NO` as mentioned above. I think you mean var.

Comment: @KeenyTM Thank you, you are correct only pointers are set to nil.

Comment: seems to be trivial but very very important to know! thanks!!

Comment: @KennyTM "non-object types like BOOL with ARC enabled will still be initialized to garbage". Are you sure about that? The link you provide says "Instance variables of Objective-C objects are always set to 0 (or nil) when you allocate an object" and I cannot find any other, clearer, reference, so it's all a bit contradictory to me.

Comment: In my case, BOOL local variable is set to 0xC8, which is 11001000, by default. Local non-object variable should always be initialized, that's what I have learned.

Comment: in my case, BOOL local variable is set to 0, that's NO. but when build in Release mode, it will be YES.

Answer (score 25):

I did some experiments of my own using Xcode 5.1, OS X Mavericks 10.9.4. For those who don’t know ALog is a modified NSLog. Anyway, first experiment was to use `isLandscape` as a public variable, with `@synthesize`, to be accessed by parent view controller (displayed below). Second experiment did not use `@synthesize` and I, obviously, used `self.isLandscape` to get the same result in the console. The console output is below my code. Third experiment used ‘isLandscape’ as a local variable inside a method.

```
@interface MyClass : UIView // (subclass used in my UIViewController)
…
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isLandscape;  // < - - - testing this BOOL
…

@implementation MyClass
…
@synthesize isLandscape;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Test for YES or NO
    if (isLandscape == YES) {
        ALog(@"isLandscape == YES");
    } else if (isLandscape == NO) {
        ALog(@"isLandscape == NO");
    } else {
        ALog(@"isLandscape != YES/NO");
    }
    // Test for nil or non-nil
    if (isLandscape) {
        ALog(@"isLandscape");
    } else if (!isLandscape) {
        ALog(@"!isLandscape");
    } else {
        ALog(@"!= nil/non-nil");
    }
    // Test its value
    ALog(@"isLandscape == %d", isLandscape);
}
```

These results are from the first two experiments…

```
2014-08-28 08:18:52.909 MyApp[493:60b] -[MyClass awakeFromNib] [Line 157] isLandscape == NO
2014-08-28 08:18:52.911 MyApp[493:60b] -[MyClass awakeFromNib] [Line 166] !isLandscape
2014-08-28 08:18:52.912 MyApp[493:60b] -[MyClass awakeFromNib] [Line 172] isLandscape == 0
```

In the THIRD EXPERIMENT ‘isLandscape’ was no longer a property. I set it to be a local variable with interesting results:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    BOOL isLandscape; // < - - - testing this BOOL
    // Test for YES or NO
    if (isLandscape == YES) {
        ALog(@"isLandscape == YES");
    } else if (isLandscape == NO) {
        ALog(@"isLandscape == NO");
    } else {
        ALog(@"isLandscape != YES/NO");
    }
    // Test for nil or non-nil
    if (isLandscape) {
        ALog(@"isLandscape");
    } else if (!isLandscape) {
        ALog(@"!isLandscape");
    } else {
        ALog(@"!= nil/non-nil");
    }
    // Test its value
    ALog(@"isLandscape == %d", isLandscape);
}
```

These results are from the third experiment…

```
2014-08-28 08:28:33.483 MyApp[581:60b] -[MyClass awakeFromNib] [Line 159] isLandscape != YES/NO
2014-08-28 08:28:33.486 MyApp[581:60b] -[MyClass awakeFromNib] [Line 164] isLandscape
2014-08-28 08:28:33.487 MyApp[581:60b] -[MyClass awakeFromNib] [Line 172] isLandscape == -24
```

I’m guessing properties get initialized by me or Xcode automatically, but local variables get no values at all. Even so, look at [Line 164] local variable is not YES or NO but it is non-nil? I guess it is the (random) garbage value that you cannot count on. I hope this helps the next person. I learned something but I look forward to comments. Thanks and good luck!