# What will be the value of a BOOL property that I don't set?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, instance-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [default value of BOOL in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919745/default-value-of-bool-in-objective-c)

If I declare a `BOOL` property in a class, what will be its default value? If I don't set a value for the variable when creating an object of the class, is it always `NO` or will it return `YES` in any case?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528098/is-there-automatic-initialization-for-attributes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990817/objective-c-ints-always-initialized-to-0

Comment: definitely not a duplicate question either: initializing property and local variable are two different things. Good job shutting down a good question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It'll be **NO**.
**It'll be initialized to FALSE/NO,**
Because when you declare it without any value, it'll be initialized to `zero`, zero means `FALSE` or `NO`

Comment: downvote festival ? )) It seems that this answer is correct...

Comment: Reference to supporting doc here would be useful