# Odd Behaviour of BOOL in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, boolean

I might be going mad here, but previously when using a BOOL I would do something like this :

```
BOOL myBool

if (myBool) {
  NSLog@"My Bool is YES";
}
```

I.e I would assume that if myBool is equivalent to saying if myBool is YES.

Under iOS7 though I am seeing the log statement trigger even when the value of myBool is never explictily set. If it is set to NO or YES the code behaves as expected.

Has something changed here under iOS7 ?

EDIT

Just to add that this moment of madness was caused but the fact that I had been elsewhere initialising BOOLs from NSUserDefaults boolForKey method, which will return NO if no value is found for that key.

Comment: You forgot some parenthesis and a semicolon. And don't add tags to your title.

Comment: If you log out the value of myBool, you will see it has a garbage value. Any non-zero value is considered true.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919745/default-value-of-bool

Comment: When you use Bool without initialising Xcode shows warning that 
'Variable 'myBool' is uninitialized when used here'. initialize the bool variable and then use the if condition.

Comment: I don't get this warning for some reason.

Comment: @Ohnomycoco It's a warning (one of many) that can be turned on and off in Xcode. Look for `GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `myBool` is never explicitely set and it's a local variable, then its value is UNDEFINED. Therefore, it can evaluate to either YES or NO.

Aren't you getting some compiler warnings?

Comment: No compiler warnings. That makes sense - sometimes it is Yes and sometimes No. I'm guessing in the past I've always initialised the Bool's value somehow.

Comment: @Ohnomycoco `Project` - `Build Settings` - `Apple LLVM 5.0 - Warnings - All languages` - `Unitialized Variables`.

Answer (score 0):

BOOL myBool is not initialised to any value in your code so it may have any random values either YES or NO..

Initialize your myBool to some value first..